# Is it possible to set css rules based on value of non-sibling elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Say you have this code:

```
<div class="hello">
    <div class="cat dog"/>
</div>
<div class="notASibling" />
```

is it possible to set a property of notASibling, based on the class value of an element that is not a sibling? For example, in the above code I may want to set the display property of notASibling to hidden if the hello > cat class is *not* a dog.

If notASibling was a sibling of "cat dog", I could simply say:

```
.cat:not(.dog) ~ .notASibling{ display:none; }
```

Comment: certainly possible with javascript - but are you asking for a solution other than javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reach a non-sibling in pure CSS. You can do this in JavaScript. If you want a pure CSS solution, consider refactoring your DOM a bit. Maybe something like this:

```
<div class='dog'>
    <div class='hello'>
        <div />
    </div>
    <div class='notASibling' />
</div>


.cat div.notASibling {
    /* special styles for cats */
}
.dog div.notASibling {
    /* special styles for dogs */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible in CSS. Your only real option here would be to use Javascript. The jQuery library is based around the idea of using enhanced CSS selectors for selecting elements to manipulate them, and you could do that here:

```
prevWasADog = $(".notASibling").prev().children('.cat').eq(0).is('.dog');
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Spontaneously, you might think about combining the child combinator and sibling combinator, i.e. like this:

```
.notASibling ~ .hello > .cat:not(.dog) { display: none }
```

But this is not possible since in the CSS 3 selectors definition (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) selectors may only use combinators with "simple selector sequences" as their operands, not other selectors. So if you follow the W3C's grammar rules you can only use one combinator within a selector.